# WooCommerce SQL query: Join post_meta table with multiple records to posts table

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am working on woocommerce and I need to run a query to get products (wp_posts) and its meta (wp_postmeta), I have written below query and it works fine

```
select p.id,p.post_title,p.post_content,
pr.meta_value as price,
rpr.meta_value as regular_price


from be_posts p

left join be_postmeta pr on p.id=pr.post_id and pr.meta_key='_price'
left join be_postmeta rpr  on p.id=rpr.post_id and rpr.meta_key='_regular_price'

where p.post_type="product"
```

Now my problem there are a lot of product meta and I have to add to many joins.

My question is is there a better way to do what I want to acheive.

Comment: share the schema will sample data in DB-fiddle so that we can help you better

Comment: Not really. You can use `MAX(CASE WHEN...` syntax which will be clearer, but it won't be faster.

Comment: Incidentally, this is an eav model, and hence widely discussed.

Comment: You seem to need a dynamic pivot table, which is not really pretty, neither too efficient in mysql. Consider doing this transformation in application code as opposed to mysql.

Answer (score -1):

As suggested in the comments use `MAX(CASE WHEN… THEN… END)` as follows (where the table prefix, in your case, will required to be replaced from `wp_` to `be_`):

```sql
SELECT p.`ID`,
   p.`post_title`,
   p.`post_content`,
   Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_price'         AND p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS price,
   Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_regular_price' AND p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS regular_price
FROM   `wp_posts` p
   INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` pm ON  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id`
WHERE  p.`post_type` = 'product'
   AND p.`post_status` = 'publish'
```

Tested and works